# Получение данных из внешней базы в Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Мне необходимо получить/обновить/удалить данные во внешней базе, никак не относящийся к базе самого приложения. Необходимо к ней обращаться из кода. Подскажите, где это все оформить, инициализация подключения, CRUD операции. Предполагаю, что в модели. Может есть какой-то пример, как лучше всего это написать?

Comment: Откуда получаются реквизиты базы и когда? Какое их количество ожидается? Как вы хотите поддерживать соединения? На том конце ожидается только СУБД MySQL?

Comment: @D-side, база одна, только mysql, реквизиты базы я могу указать при поднятии соединения, соединения мне поддерживать не надо, надо чтобы по надобности выполнялись CRUD операции

Comment: Тогда выглядит так, будто эту базу просто надо прописать в `database.yml`, не? Если она одна всего. UPD: а то и сделать `FEDERATED`-таблицу прямо в базе приложения.

Comment: @D-side, так в `database.yml` указываются же данные базы, с которой работает приложение. Они и так есть, но мне то нужна другая база, к которой надо обратиться из кода, открыв соединение. С этой базой само приложение никак не связано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько возможных решений.

## На уровне ActiveRecord

Можно выдумать **ключ**, под которым будут храниться реквизиты удалённой базы данных, например, `external`, и внести их в `database.yml`:

```
external:
  adapter: mysql
  host: example.com
  ...
```

...а в модели указать ActiveRecord обращаться именно к той базе:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :external
end
```

...а можно указать реквизиты прямо в аргументах `establish_connection` хэшмапом, но хранить их лучше в файле конфигурации на ваш выбор. `database.yml`, если вы его не коммитите, неплохой выбор. И вообще, [вот документация к `establish_connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-establish_connection).

## На уровне MySQL

MySQL имеет [движок хранения `FEDERATED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html), который делегирует хранение данных другому MySQL-серверу. Сначала этот движок необходимо включить на уровне сервера БД, а затем создать таблицу-отражение **прямо в базе приложения**.

Rails даже не нужно будет знать о том, что данные на самом деле где-то далеко.