# Получение данных из внешней базы в Rails №2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

По [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573929/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B2-rails/574055#574055) уже задавал вопрос. Все получилось, но. Прописываю параметры подключения к внешней базе:

```
class AmethystModel < ActiveRecord::Base

@amethyst_conn = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
(
 {
  :adapter => 'mysql2',
  :database => 'RemouteDB',
  :host => 'examle.remoutehost.com',
  :username => 'root',
  :password => "root"
 }
)
end
```

Потом пытаюсь воспользоватся этим соединением:

```
def self.get_all_from_amethyst
  sql = sanitize_sql(["SELECT * from RemouteDB.param_delay order by sequence"])
  @all_amethyst = @amethyst_conn.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

Но, проблема в том, что он все-равно пытается выполнить этот запрос, используя базу, прописанную в `database.yml`. Соответственно выдает ошибку:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Table 'RemouteDB.param_delay' doesn't exist: SELECT MAX(sequence) as max from RemouteDB.param_delay)
```

Почему не воспринимаются параметры соединения, преданные в `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`? Мне необходимо задавать параметры подключения именно так, не используя `database.yml` приложения.

**UPD:**
Есть готовое Rails приложение (Redmine), у которого есть ряд моделей (Issue, Project, User, Token, etc). Мне нужно добавить туда свою логику. Есть некая внешняя база из которой мне надо получить данные. Эта база никак не связана с базой приложения. Так вот, я создал модель:

```
class AmethystModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  @amethyst_conn = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :external


  def self.get_all_from_amethyst
     sql = sanitize_sql(["SELECT * from Amethyst.param_delay order by sequence"])
      @all_amethyst = @amethyst_conn.connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

Параметры `external` описал в `database.yml`.
Где я описал ряд методов для работы с данными из этой таблицы. Также я создал view и контроллер для работы с данной моделью. Однако, после данных действий все приложение перестало работать, выдается ошибка:

```
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Table 'amethyst.tokens' doesn't exist: UPDATE `tokens` SET `tokens`.`updated_on` = '2016-10-18 14:30:29' WHERE `tokens`.`user_id` = 2921 AND `tokens`.`value` = 'fbb2e4ece07e76e9f5605ffb9549607a37b51b1a' AND `tokens`.`action` = 'session'):
app/models/user.rb:414:in `verify_session_token'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:77:in `session_expired?'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:67:in `session_expiration'
config/initializers/ntlm-sso.rb:31:in `call'
```

Предпологаю, из-за того, что во внешней базе нет таблицы `tokens`, но ее там и не должно быть, она никак не связана с приложением, мне просто нужно оттуда получить данные.
На PHP это было написано просто:

```
 $redmine_conn = new mysqli("examle.remoutehost.com", "root", "root", "RemouteDB");
```

этого было достаточно, это подключение никак не контактировало с текущим, которое использует приложение.

Comment: Вы делаете несколько не то, что я написал в своём ответе.

Comment: @D-side, lда, вы предлагали прописать в database.yml, но я хочу просто прописать connect к этой базе, без использования database.yml, забрать данные и все, больше мне ничего  от нее не нужно. Я и указал, как по документации, параметры подключения в виде хэша прямо в `establish_connection`

Comment: @D-side, я так и делал, добавлял новую запись в `database.yml` и вызывал, как вы и указали. Но в этом приложении есть таблица `tokens`, куда складываются токены пользователей (приложение Redmine), соответственно подключаясь к удаленной базе, он вываливается с ошибкой:

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Table 'amethyst.tokens' doesn't exist: UPDATE `tokens` SET `tokens`.`updated_on` = '2016-10-18 10:00:38' WHERE `tokens`.`user_id` = 2921 AND `tokens`.`value` = 'fbb2e4ece07' AND `tokens`.`action` = 'session'):app/models/user.rb:414:in `verify_session_token'`. Я не могу там создавать никакие таблицы, мне просто нужно забрать оттуда данные

Comment: @D-side, ошибка такая: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Table 'amethyst.tokens' doesn't exist: UPDATE `tokens` SET `tokens`.`updated_on` = '2016-10-18 10:00:38' WHERE `tokens`.`user_id` = 2921 AND `tokens`.`value` = 'fbb2e4ece07e76e9f5605ffb9549607a37b51b1a' AND `tokens`.`action` = 'session'):
  app/models/user.rb:414:in `verify_session_token'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:77:in `session_expired?'`. Возникает при попытке забора данных с внешней базы

Comment: @D-side, добавил информацию в вопрос

Comment: Я всё ещё не понимаю, почему бы вам просто не сделать класс модели, прибитый к внешней базе, так же как я это описал в своём ответе по ссылке.

Comment: @D-side, я же так и сделал: `class AmethystModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  @amethyst_conn = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :external`

end

Comment: Нет, не так. Перечитайте мой ответ ещё раз. Обратите особое внимание на то, **у чего (где)** я вызываю метод `establish_connection`.